# simplicial commutive rings as algebra objects in a symmetric monoidal category

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory

Do simplicial commutative rings arise as the commutative algebra objects in some symmetric monoidal infinity category? If I understand correctly, I think $E_\infty$ rings are the commutative algebra objects in the symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category $Sp$ of spectra.

(Obviously I am a beginner in such things. References to where I can learn more about simplicial commutative rings are welcome).

Comment: Simplicial commutative rings are a strict notion and so live in an ordinary category, not an $\infty$-category. They are indeed commutative monoids – in the symmetric monoidal category of simplicial abelian groups. Just do everything degreewise.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks, that makes sense.